# Applications and implementation of Mapping Array with integer universe to fixed range

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, functional-programming, binary-search

Let's say you are given integer array which can take entire integer space. But, I want to map that to fixed range.

**For ex:** `{1, 5, 38, 5, 2^32-1}    --->   {1, 2, 3, 2, 4}` Please note the duplicated element value '5' and it's mapping array. And **order** is not relavant.

Are there any applications of doing above apart from Fenwick Tree ( Fenwick tree requires range of 1..N ) ?

One way is to do this is,

```
int[] map( int[]  a) {
    int[] transArr = new int[a.length];
    Map<Integer,Integer> posValueMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i= 0 ; i < a.length; i++) {
       if(!posValueMap.contains(i))
          posValueMap.put(a[i], i);
    }
    for(int i= 0 ; i < transArr.length; i++) {
        transArr[i] = posValueMap.get(a[i]);
    }
    return transArr;
}
```

Is there a much simpler way to achieve this with a different **algorithm**, or functional programming constructs ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need some kind of [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

**Minimal perfect hash** function maps set of N distinct elements to N integer keys in range 0..N-1 or 1..N, as you wants.

(There are open source libraries for MPH)